# How can I change the two figure behavior with my MacBook Pro (6,2)'s trackpad?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, mac

By default on mac os, with two fingers I can do this:
-leave a finger on the mouse pad, and move another finger, and still be able to move the mouse
-two finger scrolling requires both fingers be moving

this is handy, as sometimes (because the trackpad is so large, I leave my thumb on the "button" (or any other fingers depending on how I'm sitting) for clicking, as clicking AND moving the cursor at the same time is difficult with this track pad (the whole thing needs to be pressed to click)

I think this probably also affects click and drag, as I would only be allowed to use one finger, instead of one finger to click, and the other to move the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the mouse settings under system preferences? On my MacBook Air I have some settings there. I'm using the Synaptics driver. If there are no extra settings under the mouse and touchpad bit then you can try the following providing synaptics is installed:

```
synclient TapButton3=2 ClickFinger3=2 PalmDetect=1
```

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Just applied the changes. Not sure what each of those does. But so far I've noticed, that two fingers on the trackpad MUST scroll -- rather than leaving one stationary, and moving the other to move the cursor. =\